# Docker-compose connect multiple projects

Tags: docker, docker-compose

As the title explains i'm trying to connect 2 instances of docker-compose together.
One is the data api, and the other is the actual application.

The solutions i've found are all docker-compose v2 or v1, nothing for version 3.

I've so far tried a normal docker-compose, but cant ping from one to the other.
I've also tried adding networks, but this creates networks like this:
DataAPI_network
FrontEnd_network
So they're not connecting to the same network.

I don't think i need to share actual code for this, if you want to know something more, please just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark your network as external in your compose files.
The network will need to be pre-existing (create it using `docker network create` before calling `docker-compose up`).

See documentation, at the end of this page : https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network

BTW there is the same concept of external volumes.

Comment: Thank you, creating the network first and then adding it to the containers is the way it makes sense to work, just couldn't figure it out.